# Pivot table with 2 different sheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 2 different excel sheets

tab1

```
  A B C D E
1
2
3
```

and table 2

```
  T U V W X
1
2
3
```

Let's say in  B and U columns we have the same kind of data for instance "name of owner" and in C and V we have "number of animals owned", in D and W we have "country of the animal". The oter data are not relevant for my pivot table but I still want to be able to find them if needed.

I want a single pivot table which uses tab 1 and 2.
I want to have D (or W as they are the same type of data) as filter and to see for every "name of the owner" the "number of animals owned" according to tab1 in a column and in another column the "number of animals owned" ccording to tab2.

I tried to use the pivot table helper but I didn't manage to use filters and I could obtain a pivot table by "name of owner" only if I used the datasets with as a first column B and U.

Thank you.

Comment: Morg, this belongs on super user. As an aside, you might have some luck by naming your data ranges, and referring to those names in your pivot table.

Comment: Have you looked into the PowerPivot extension?

Comment: Unfortunately i do not have excel 2010 on my computer